# Displaying Videos in a WPF window

Tags: wpf

I need to ask you some questions. I'm new in developing with C# and WPF applications and i don't know what to do.
I have a list of links (videos) that are stocked in a data base and i need to display them in wpf window. I have searched in the internet but I didn't found something interesting
Would you please help me with some tutorials or the steps that I need to follow.
This is an example of what i have to do:
[image: THis is a screen capture of i want to do: a list of videos with thumbnails]

Comment: Take a look at the [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) control.

Comment: i have looked at the MediaElement control. and i know it.the videos worked fine(with youtube video player) but i need to display them in a list like the photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  to a list of your video objects, then apply a [template](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) to those objects to render them in a MediaElement, you can then customise how the ItemsControl is layed out by customising the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`

Update for swf:

To play swf files, as long as you are happy that you can't control the playback, you can use a WebBrowser, setting the Source property to the .swf file.

```
<WebBrowser Source="myvideo.swf" />
```

Comment: they are youtube videos and they don't work in a MediaElement control.
Thank you for your response but i didn't get much.
Would you please explain!!!!

Comment: Putting the media format aside for the moment, to get a layout like in your screenshot in WPF I recommend you use an ItemsControl. Check out my second link in my answer above for some really nice examples of how this works.